# If $f\in C_0(E)$ with $\inf_{x\in E}f(x)<\infty$, then there is a $x\in E$ with $f(x)\le\min(f,0)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $E$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $$C_0(E):=\left\{f\in C(E):\left\{|f|\ge\varepsilon\right\}\text{ is compact for all }\varepsilon>0\right\}.$$

> Let $f\in C_0(E)$ with $$\inf_{x\in E}f(x)<0\tag1.$$ How can we show that there is a $x_0\in E$ with $$f(x_0)\le\min(f(x),0)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in E\tag2?$$

I guess we can simply apply the fact$^1$ that if $g\in C_0(E)$, there is a $x_0\in E$ with $|g(x_0)|=\sup_{x\in E}|g(x)|$ to the function $g:=\min(f,0)$ or am I missing something?

---

$^1$ Assume $E$ is a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space and $g\not\equiv0$. Then there is a $x_1\in E$ with $\varepsilon:=|g(x_1)|>0$. Since $\left\{|g|\ge\varepsilon\right\}$ is compact, there is a $r>0$ with $$|g(x)|<\varepsilon\;\;\;\text{for all }\left\|x\right\|_E>r.\tag1$$ By continuity of $g$ and compactness of the closed ball around $0\in E$ with radius $r$, there is a $x_0\in E$ with $$|g(x_0)|=\sup_{\left\|x\right\|_E\:\le\:r}|g(x)|\ge\varepsilon\tag4.$$ Maybe we can use a similar argumentation even when $E$ is a general locally compact Hausdorff space.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that $\sup_{x \in E} |g(x)|$ might be $+ \infty$. First, you have to prove that this is not the case.

Comment: @Crostul I've added the proof to the question. If there is no mistake in the proof, $\sup_{x \in E} |g(x)|$ is impossible (since the proof shows that $|g|$ attains its supremum). Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by $|| \cdot ||_E$? There is no assumption on $E$ to a normed space, indeed it might not even be a metric space.

Comment: @Crostul Sorry, copied that from a context where $E$ was a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space. Can we adopt the arguments in the general case?

Comment: It isn't possible that $\sup_{x\in E} |g(x)| = \infty$. In that case define $K = \left\{|g| \ge \frac12 \sup_{x\in E} |g(x)| \right\}$ so $\sup_{x \in E}|g(x)| = \sup_{x \in K} |g(x)| < \infty$ because $|g|\big|_K$ is bounded since  $K$ is compact.

Comment: @mechanodroid Don't get your argument. You say "in that case", hence I assume you mean the aforementioned case, $\sup_{x\in E} |g(x)| = \infty$. But then $K=\emptyset$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yeah, I messed it up a bit. Assume $\sup_{x\in E} |g(x)| = \infty$ and define $K = \{|g| \ge 1\}$. Then $$\infty = \sup_{E} |g| = \sup_{K} |g|$$
since $|g| < 1$ on $E \setminus K$. But this is a contradiction since $|g|\big|_K$ is supposed to be bounded because $K$ is compact.

Comment: @mechanodroid Okay, and I guess we conclude that $|g|$ attains its supremum on $K$.

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: @mechanodroid I think I was too hasty. We need to assume that $g\not\equiv0$ (in which case the claim is trivial) to ensure that there is a $x_0\in E$ with $\varepsilon:=|g(x_0)|>\varepsilon$. Now we can invoke your argument with $1$ replaced by $\varepsilon$ (i.e. $K:=\left\{|g|\ge\varepsilon\right\}$). Then the supremum is indeed attained on $K$. Your approach fails if $|g|<1$ on the whole space$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I was working uder the assumption that $\sup_E |g| = \infty$ so clearly it cannot be $|g| < 1$ on the whole space, nor $g \equiv 0$.

Comment: @mechanodroid I know and your proof is perfectly fine to show that $\sup_E|g|=\infty$ is impossible. My comment was related to my subsequent question about how we can show that $|g|$ actually attains its supremum. Using $\varepsilon$ instead proves both at the same time.

Comment: @0xbadf00d True. I actually used the same approach in the answer below with $K = \{|g| \ge \frac12\sup_E |g|\}$, once we know that $\sup_E |g|< \infty$, but yours is more elegant as it does it in one take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, for $g \in C_0(E)$ there exists $x_0 \in E$ such that $|g(x_0)| = \sup _{x\in E}|g(x)|$:

The set $K = \left\{|g| \ge \frac12 \sup _{x\in E}|g(x)| \right\}$ is compact so $|g|\big|_K$ attains its maximum, i.e. there exists $x_0 \in E$ such that $$|g(x_0)| = \sup_{x \in K}|g(x)|$$
But we have $|g(x)| < \frac12 \sup _{x\in E}|g(x)|$ for $x \notin K$ so
$$|g(x_0)| = \sup_{x \in K}|g(x)| = \sup_{x \in E}|g(x)|$$

Applying this to $g = \min(f,0)$ we have $|g| = |f|\chi_{\{f < 0\}}$ so $f(x_0) \le 0$.

Also, if $f(x) < 0$ then $|g(x)| = |f(x)|$ so for such $x$ we have
$$f(x_0) = -|g(x_0)| \le -|g(x)| = f(x)$$
Therefore $f(x_0) \le g(x)$ for all $x \in E$.

Comment: No, I wish to show that there is a $x_0\in E$ with $f(x_0)\le\min(f(x),0)$ for all $x\in E$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Have a look now, the same strategy you outlined applies for general LCH space $E$.

Comment: Got a related question, could you take a look? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3151701/47771