# If a closable linear operator satisfies the nonnegative maximum principle, does the same apply to its closure?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $E$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $(\mathcal D(A),A)$ be a closable linear operator on $C_0(E)$. If $(\mathcal D(A),A)$ satisfies the nonnegative maximum principle$^1$, does the same apply to the closure $(\mathcal D(\overline A),\overline A)$?

Let $f\in\mathcal D(A)$ and $x_0\in E$ with $\max(0,f(x))\le f(x_0)$. By definition of $(\mathcal D(\overline A),\overline A)$, there is a $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal D(A)$ with $$\left\|f_n-f\right\|_\infty\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag1$$ and $$\left\|Af_n-\overline Af\right\|_\infty\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag2.$$ Now, [it can be shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3151288/47771) that there is a $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq E$ with $$|f_n(x_n)|=\left\|f_n\right\|_\infty\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N.\tag3$$ Note that $$\tilde f_n:=f_n\operatorname{sgn}f_n(x_n)\in\mathcal D(A)$$ and $$\tilde f_n(x_n)=\left\|f_n\right\|_\infty\ge0$$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Moreover, $$\left|\tilde f_n(x_n)-f(x_0)\right|=\left|\left\|f_n\right\|_\infty-\left\|f\right\|_\infty\right|\le\left\|f_n-f\right\|_\infty\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag4.$$

How can we conclude? Maybe we need to assume the contrary ...

---

$^1$ If $f\in\mathcal D(A)$ and $x_0\in E$ with $\max(0,f(x))\le f(x_0)$ for all $x\in E$, then $(Af)(x_0)\le0$.

Comment: @reuns https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator#Closed_linear_operators.

Comment: Defining closable can help. $D(A)$ is a (dense ?) subspace of $E$ and $\|f\|_A = \|f\|_{C_0(E)}+\|Af\|_{C_0(E)}$ is a norm on $D(A)$ and closable means there is a subspace $D(\overline{A})$ of $C_0(E)$ such that $D(\overline{A}),\|.\|_A$ is the completion of $D(A),\|.\|_A$ so $\|.\|_{C_0(E)}$ is a norm on that completion.

Comment: @reuns Some comments appear to be missing so I might have missed something but the last few words of your comment feel misleading to me. It's true that $\|\cdot\|_{C_0^\infty(E)}$ will always be a norm on a subspace of $C_0^\infty(E)$ but this isn't special. It won't usually induce the topology of the completion. There are closed linear operators $A$ (equivalently, which are closable with $\overline{A}= A$) such that $D(A) = D(\overline{A})$ is a dense proper subset of $C_0^\infty$ and so can't be complete (e.g. usual examples of generators of $C_0$-semigroups)

Comment: @RhysSteele I meant closable operator on Banach space $\|.\|_E$. See [p.3](http://faculty.tcu.edu/richardson/Seminars/unbounded.pdf) for an example of non-closable operator : $F(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x(t)dt$ unbounded linear map $ L^2(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{C}$ and $A (x)(t) = F(x)e^{-t^2 \pi/2}$ then $\|x\|_A = \|x\|_{ L^2(\mathbb{R})} +|F(x)| $, pick $\|y_n\|_{ L^2(\Bbb{R})} \to 0, F(y_n) \to 1$ (for example $y_n(t) =\frac{1}{F(y_n)}\frac{1_{t\in[1,n]}}{t}$) then the completion of $D(A),\|.\|_A$ is $y_\infty\Bbb{C} \oplus L^2(\Bbb{R})$ where $\|y_n-y_\infty\|_A \to 0, \|y_\infty\|_A = 1$

Comment: @reuns I have no idea why you are mentioning non-closable operators, they have nothing to do with my comment since here we have assumed the operator $A$ is closable (though I am well aware of examples so did not need the link). Let me state my last comment differently as you appear to have misunderstood. The graph norm on $(D(\overline{A}),\overline{A})$ is not equivalent to the norm of the ambient Banach space in general and so here it is strange to note that $\|\cdot\|_{C_0^\infty}$ is a norm on the completion since it doesn't induce the topology of the completion.

Comment: @RhysSteele In functional analysis "the $\|.\|_{C_0^\infty}$ norm" doesn't refer to anything. With $A x(t) = x'(t)$ on $L^2(\Bbb{R})$ the completion of $D(A),\|.\|_A$ is $H^1(\Bbb{R})$ and $\|.\|_{L^2(\Bbb{R})}$ is a norm on it, not a semi-norm, thus $A$ is closable, even if of course $\|.\|_{H^1(\Bbb{R})}$ and $\|.\|_{L^2(\Bbb{R})}$ aren't equivalent

Comment: @reuns  Apologies, I made a typo. I just meant to type $\|\cdot \|_{C_0}$. However can I suggest you mind your tone, trying to tell me what is the norm in functional analysis comes across as fairly condescending. For the second thing, sure. Note I said this in the context of $C_0^\infty(E)$ earlier ("It's true that $\|\cdot\|_{C_0^\infty}$ will always be a norm on a subspace of $C_0^\infty(E)$"). My claim was that this statement is misleading, not that it is false. What is misleading is that you mention it despite the fact that it is irrelevant to the definition of the closability.

Comment: @reuns *Closable* is defined as in the Wikipedia article or [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=eSZqJOaiRUwC&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=%22ouhabaz%22+%22closable%22&source=bl&ots=BWesmY-pdT&sig=ACfU3U27dDeLnpOM9h5zb97WDIf_qbKhEQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjiv_y2uJrhAhUJMuwKHWG6CrEQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22ouhabaz%22%20%22closable%22&f=false) in Definition 1.36. $\mathcal D(A)$ is not assumed to be dense.

Comment: @RhysSteele It might be possible to show the desired claim by arguments as given [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=uL7UBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA323&lpg=PA323&dq=%22for+all+sufficiently+large%22+%22kallenberg%22&source=bl&ots=iip0jbHV6i&sig=ACfU3U0btp61oBxwS2CfV0jqH5BG0dqHTg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_yoC6uZrhAhUK3qQKHbvCB_oQ6AEwCXoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22for%20all%20sufficiently%20large%22%20%22kallenberg%22&f=false) at the end of the proof of Theorem 17.11.